# How to show that $f(x) = \text{sup}_{ i \in I}f_i(x)$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

**Given:**
$I$ is an index and let for each $i \in I, f_i:\mathbb{R} \to [0,2019]$ be continuous
$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = \text{sup}_{ i \in I}f_i(x)$.

**Problem:**
Would like to show: $f$ is measurable using that if $\forall r \in \mathbb{R}
    ,f^{-1}((r,\infty))\in\mathcal{A}$, then $f$ is measurable.

**My thoughts**
In some way should show that $\forall B \in \mathcal{B}$ (which is the $\sigma$ - algebra on $[0,2019]$) $, f^{-1}(B)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. $f_i$ is continuous, so use that $f^{-1}(B)$ is open if B is open.
Both don't know how to finish this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the open intervals $(a, \infty)$ generate the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets and $f^{-1}((a, \infty))=\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid a < f(x) \}=\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid \exists{i \in I}, a < f_i(x) \}= \cup_{i \in I} f_i^{-1}((a, \infty))$ is open.